# Android Retrofit Json Model Class

Tags: android, retrofit

I am getting the following json response:

```
{"data":{"date":1449750694,"home":[{"secId":"43","homePriority":"1",etc...
```

For this above response how shall i create a model class... please help.

Comment: could you paste all response?

Comment: "data": {
"date": 1449741739
"home": [6]
0:  {
"secId": "43"
"homePriority": "1"
"secName": "TOP NEWS"
"type": "TN"
}-
1:  {
"secId": "68"
"homePriority": "2"
"secName": "BREAKING NEWS"
"type": "BK"
}-
2:  {
"secId": "5"
"homePriority": "3"
"secName": "OPINION"
"type": "GN"
}-
3:  {
"secId": "52"
"homePriority": "4"
"secName": "ENTERTAINMENT"
"type": "GN"
}-
4:  {
"secId": "6"
"homePriority": "5"
"secName": "SPORTS"
"type": "GN"
}-
5:  {
"secId": "7"
"homePriority": "6"
"secName": "BUSINESS"
"type": "GN"
}

Comment: it is not valid format of json.

Comment: This is a poor question. The json you pasted is invalid and there is no attempt at all at researching the problem. Before posting on SO, please go through this tutorial: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Your Json is incorrect !

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to generate model classes is to use **[jsonschema2pojo.com](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)**. Copy - Paste your JSON response to jsonschema2pojo and they generate the desired Modal classes for you.

***It is by far the best and easiest way. Try using third party tools like this for improving productivity***

Comment: thanks for your kind response. I have tried with my json response not able to create a POJO Class

Comment: Well it's fairly simple, copy and paste the response into jsonschema2pojo.com, if it says error in line number, then there is a error in your json response, basically means wrong json syntax. In that case try jsonlint.com to check the syntax. Correct the syntax, and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

json to pojo(Model)

paste your json respose source [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and you will get your model class.

Comment: thanks for your kind response. I have tried with my json response not able to create a POJO Class

Answer (score 0):

By far the best way to create Model Class is to use DTO Generator plugin available for android studio.
Here is the link for it.
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7834-dto-generator
. Once you download it, extract.
Go to Android Studio->File-Settings->Plugins->Install Plugin from disk and navigate to the DTO Generator.
Restart the IDE.
Create a new Java Class and right click. Go to Generate-> DTO from JSON. Paste your JSON there and Android Studio will create the Model Classes  for you!